# Why there is a maximum of 4096 queues in WFQ?

Tags: cisco, routing, qos

In QoS there is a variety of Queuing methods and one of them is [WFQ](/tags/wfq), which organizes the flows in different queues where each queue has a weight that determines which flow will go first.

Now for calculating the weight the formula used is:

Weight = 4096 / (IP-precedence+1). Where 4096 is the maximum number of queues, so why the maximum number is 4096? It is a pre-established number or it is based on some criteria?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This platform specific limit, so it's just arbitrary limit Cisco came up with at one point in time, probably driven by memory restrictions of device of that era.

> W=K/(precedence +1)
>
> K= 4096 with Cisco IOS 12.0(4)T and earlier releases, and 32384 with
>   12.0(5)T and later releases.

From: 
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk543/tk545/technologies_q_and_a_item09186a00800cdfab.shtml#class

Comment: Cisco applied many changes to their QoS internals during the years. If you're interested in the topic i would recommend you to read these links: [Insights on CBWFQ](http://blog.ine.com/2008/08/17/insights-on-cbwfq/), [Understanding Queue Limits and Output Drops on Cisco IOS Software Platforms](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps341/products_tech_note09186a0080af893d.shtml)